# Save motion output videos in USB Drive

Tags: permissions, usb, usb-drive, chmod, motion

I'm using a USB drive in my Raspberry to store my website. Now I want also save my videos made with `motion`.

I wasn't able to save in a folder different from `/tmp/motion` so googling I found I had to give permission to the folder where I wanted to use.

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /path/
```

I tried in the user directory `/home/pi` and it worked, then I tried the same on my USB drive.

- Filesystem /dev/sda1
- Size 3.6G
- Used 1.3M
- Avail 3.6G
- Use% 1%
- Mounted On /home/pi/usbdrv

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /home/pi/usbdrv
```

But didn't work.

---

**Some info:**

So

```
$ sudo service motion start
```

motion start working, I can see images via browser, but as soon as the webcam try to save a file (e.g. a photo) the thread of the webcam crash. Trying stop motion in the same way

```
$ sudo service motion stop
```

I get

```
[....] Stopping motion detection demon: motionNo /usr/bin/motion found running; none killed.
. ok
```

else if there are more webcams service still run until when all of them try to save datas.

---

**Another test:**
While if I try, always from terminal:

```
$ sudo motion
```

I get

```
[0] Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] Processing config file /etc/motion/thread1.conf
[0] Processing config file /etc/motion/thread2.conf
[0] Motion 3.2.12 Started
[0] Exit motion, cannot create process id file (pid file) /var/run/motion/motion.pid: No such file or directory
[0] Motion going to daemon mode
$
```

PS: I have two thread file, because I have two webcams

---

**My USB:**

```
/dev/sda1 on /home/pi/usbdrv type vfat (rw,nosuid,relatime,sync,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors,remount-ro)
```

---

**More info:**
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=75136

Comment: Can you fix the first `chmod 777` command? That does nothing w/o a directory or file to operate against.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want say that chmod 777 is the command I found which give permissions

Comment: motion use by default /tmp/motion, I'm able to save videos and images in user directory and other directories, but not in my usb drive, also after that command

Comment: What's the distro you're using?

Comment: Tip: if some tutorial tells you to do `chmod 777`, it means the author of the tutorial has no idea what they're doing and is flailing blindly in the dark. Close the tutorial and don't follow any of its recommendations. Now, explain to us your real problem — what did you change in the configuration of Motion? Or did it always crash before you started messing about with permissions? What are you doing to “save” your videos: are you copying some files? Where and with what tool? or using the “Save” menu in some software?

Comment: Well, motion is a software which records webcam stream (a security system), it used by default /tmp/motion to save file e never crashed. But I want videos in my USB Drive, so from motion configuration file I changed directory, but the program crashed as soon as it tried to save the file in the USB Drive directory, mounted as /home/pi (I'm using Raspbian on my Raspberry), so I searched on iternet founding chmod, I used both in user direcory and usb drive. In user dir it worked, while in USB drive it doesn't

Comment: `chmod 777` will fail with an explicit error ("missing operand after 777").

Comment: Yes I know, after that I wrote every path I ve tried (user directory and documents which now work and usb drive which still doesn't work)

Comment: It looks like you have mis-configured, the error says can not create "/var/run/motion/motion.pid", have you looked at that file `ls -l` You must also give us the 3 configuration files which you are using.

Comment: I've just added a link where I wrote configuration files and result of ls

Comment: I've the solution, could you re-open the question?